# Merging Faces, How?

Tags: faces

i'm fairly new to Blender and i ran into something i couldn't solve for thr last 30 min or so, googling my problem did not really help, how would i merge the selected faces into one ?
Anyone have an idea, would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Select the edges that are connecting (separating) the faces, then right click > dissolve edges

Comment: Jesus Christ, such a simple solution,Thank You Sir.

Comment: Hello :). You can also press **F** with the faces selected. However, it's often desirable to keep quad topology.